# What do I need to change/add in order to add a field to the block struct?

Tags: blockchain

I'm trying to add a field to the block struct, and want it to be serialized just like the miner_tx and the tx_hashes (like FIELD(new_field)), because the block parsing is failing for me with my code ("Failed to parse block from blob" occurs when I start monerod and then it exits).
What should I change in the code that can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would edit the block struct in `https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_basic.h` by adding the extra variable and specifying the serialization field correct to the type of your variable.

Comment: The problem was, as you said in the comment, that all the others blocks on the blockchain didn't construct with this variable, and it sorted out when I opened new testnet blockchain from scartch. Thank you!